# Adding an array of hex values together

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of hex values in node js that has hex values such as this: ['2ea','1b1'...]. The array does not have a fixed amount of values. The amount of values can change each time. I have been trying to come up with a for loop that would add the hex values up. But it isnt working. Please help. The code below is not correct.

```
for (var i=0; i<checkSumArray.length; i++) {
  function CheckSumFinal(c1, c2) {
        var hexStr = (parseInt(c1, 16) + parseInt(c2, 16)).toString(16);
        return hexStr;
      }

      var n7= CheckSumFinal(checkSumArray[i], checkSumArray[i+1]);

    }
```

Comment: Move `CheckSumFinal` out of the loop for starters, you don't need to declare it over and over again.

Comment: n7 is going to get overwritten on every loop, which means you'll only ever get results for `check[n-1] + check[n]`

Comment: How can i get n7 to be not overwritten each time?

Answer (score 3):

For calculating sums over an array `reduce` would be perfect. The idea is to calculate the sum first and just convert the final answer to base16 string.

```
checkSumArray.reduce(function(p, c){
  return p + parseInt(c, 16);
}, 0).toString(16);
```

Comment: Since this is node.js, an arrow function would make this nicer. `(p, c) => p + parseInt(c, 16)`

Comment: Yea, I just decided not to put arrow function there cause I see OP uses the old function declaration, no idea what version of node he uses.

Comment: @jay Correct, `reduce` does the looping for you. It calls the function on each element, where the first parameter is the running total, and the second parameter is an element from `checkSumArray`. The `return` of one iteration is the first parameter of the next iteration. Here's the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2):

Keep the variables outside the loop, and just add up inside the loop

```js
var checkSumArray = ['2ea','1b1', 'fff', '4a1', '1e1'],
    hexStr = 0;

for (var i=0; i<checkSumArray.length; i++) {
    hexStr += parseInt(checkSumArray[i], 16);
}

hexStr = hexStr.toString(16);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + hexStr + '</pre>'
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to concatenate the digits. A sum seems to be required.